# I need a timestamp input for an html form. Don't know if this is possible but I'm just starting out

Tags: html, input

So like I say i dont know if I am doing any of this correctly but I am basically teaching myself and I don't seem to be able to find anything about having a timestamp input field. It is actually for inputting timestamps from movies.

```
<div id="form"><form>
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
Movie Title: <input type="text" name="movietitle">
<p>Is the drink...</p>
<input type="radio" name="drinktype" value="alcoholic">Alcoholic
<input type="radio" name="drinktype" value="soft">Non-alcoholic
<p>What exact time did the Buffalo occur during the movie?</p>
<input type="time" name="timestamp"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form></div>
```

I'm not showing anything CCS-wise for this because what I really want to know how to do is a timestamp input field first in this format hh:mm:ss

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Do you care if the time is inaccurate? Doing it serverside with javascript would give you the client's time, while doing it server-side would give you the server's time. Something to consider.

Comment: You will have to get this serverside (ie. PHP's `date()` method)

Comment: This code should work. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: Thanks Alec and Zac but I meant a user input time for hours minutes and seconds. i.e. when did you hear something happen e.g. in a song as an input. This code doesn't show me any seconds field and it doesn't really need to go past 2 or 3 in the hours field either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `step` attribute in your `input` tag:

```
<input type="time" name="timestamp" step="1">
```

W3C: [input: type=time](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, however, for interest sake alone this doesn't work particularly well in Safari as the field will allow any input even if value="time" is used. Works fine in Chrome though.

Comment: As you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input, in Safari `time` is recognized but has no UI. I guess you could make one using javascript for unsupported browsers, but that kinda removes any reason to use `type=time`, since you can simply use your code for all browsers.

Comment: How can I input a datetime